# Why does this CSS code give a weird border between modal body and footer?

Tags: css

I have managed to repoduce the problem, but it has to be run on a chrome browser.

https://jsbin.com/hadavayosi/edit?html,css,output

Basically there is a gray border between the modal__body and modal__footer, this border disappears if I comment out `font: 13px/1.5em sans-serif;` from the body element, or comment out both `height` and `line-height` from the button element. The border also disappears if I remove the text inside modal__body element.

This is how the problem looks like:

[image]

There is a grayish border/separator between the modal body and footer. This appears on Chrome browser and not on Firefox.

```css
body {
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  font: 13px/1.5em sans-serif;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.modal {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.modal--darker-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 2px rgba(#000, 0.2);
}

.modal__body {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}

.modal__footer {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(#000, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal login-modal modal--darker-shadow">
  <div class="modal__body">
    Why border?
  </div>
  <div class="modal__footer">
    <button class="button">Logg inn</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have reproduced the issue here:
https://jsbin.com/hadavayosi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: If you used bootstrap modal then there is a line between header, body, and footer.

Comment: This is not bootstrap, it is a few lines of code

Comment: When you change the font in the body to `font: 12px/1.5em sans-serif;` the border disappears

Comment: But why? It makes no sense to force me to use 12px.

Comment: Now, even I am concerned why

Comment: If I change it to font: 13px/1.4em sans-serif; or font: 13px/1.6em sans-serif; then the border disappears too

Comment: @Alex please see the my answer you have just need to remove font family your font family some how added the border.

Comment: Sachin Sarola what if I want that font family? I need to understand why this happens, it is a really weird bug

Comment: Something related: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/margin-difference-between-chrome-and-other-browsers/#post-160374 I find the problem in Opera too.

Comment: @Alex normally sans-serif doesn't behave as in your code so try to find some other sans-serif font from some weher and include this font into your page/project

Comment: What you see is not a border, but the background color of the body. Change the background color of the body and you will notice. There is a one pixel gap between model__body and modal__footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is primarily because of the `transform`. The transform is resulting in half pixel measurements which obviously can't be rendered. There are errors introduced and the background color of the page comes through. To demonstrate this lets give the modal a background color of red to make it obvious.

**DEMO BELOW**

```css
body {
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    font: 13px/1.5em sans-serif;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.modal {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.modal--darker-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 2px rgba(#000, 0.2);
    background-color:#F00;
}

.modal__body {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: white;
}

.modal__footer {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #dddddd;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(#000, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.modal.no-transform {
transform:none;
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal login-modal modal--darker-shadow">
    <div class="modal__body">
        Why border?
    </div>
    <div class="modal__footer">
        <button class="button">Logg inn</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal login-modal modal--darker-shadow no-transform">
    <div class="modal__body">
        Why no border? No Transform!
    </div>
    <div class="modal__footer">
        <button class="button">Log inn</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So what to do?**

Either center you box with an alternate to transform or give your modal a background color that masks the issue.

```css
body {
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    font: 13px/1.5em sans-serif;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.modal {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.modal--darker-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 2px rgba(#000, 0.2);
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
}

.modal__body {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: white;
}

.modal__footer {
    padding: 15px;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #dddddd;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(#000, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal login-modal modal--darker-shadow">
    <div class="modal__body">
        Why border?
    </div>
    <div class="modal__footer">
        <button class="button">Logg inn</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case if I replaced body rules with this one than its worked properly 
body {
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    font-size: 13px/1.5em;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

Would you please explain in detail ?

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any suggestion to how I should add a footer top border on this modal? A 1px separator. Right now it does not work the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with the top-padding settings. When you give both objects more padding (top or bottom) then this "border" gets invisible.

Comment: But why are there a border there at all? We have not specified a border, it just magically appears, it would be nice to know and understand :)

Comment: Where did you add top-padding?

Comment: It looks like it's more a browser "auto"-border when the padding bottom from modal_body is between 1px and 19px. When its more than 20px it's gone

Comment: <div class="modal__body" style="
    padding-bottom: 20px;
">
            Why border?
        </div>

Comment: Yes but if I want overall padding it comes back.

Answer (score 0):

May be its because of body css rules if you remove font family the border will not displayed some how font family will added the border.I have no idea why font family added the border to the div so check once remove the font family.

```
body {
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    font: 13px/1.5em sans-serif;
}
```

Hope it will make sense

Correct format of above rule

```
body {
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    font-size: 13px/1.5em;
   font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Now try adding a border-top: 1px soild #d1d1d1; on .modal__footer. You get two borders!!!

Comment: @alex used some think like below..

body {
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    font-size: 13px/1.5em;
   font-family: sans-serif;
}